# Searching issue in my project

Tags: javafx

I am making a project using javaFx and I need to search nth match of given string in a text. There is a button in my project and on first click it is supposed to find first match and on 2nd click it should find 2nd match and so one.For this I wrote following code using lambda expression

```
int pos=0;
b1.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    String str=ta.getText();    //given text
    String srch=t1.getText();   //string to be searched
    pos = str.indexOf(srch,pos+1);
    ta.selectRange(pos, pos+srch.length());
});
```

But I am getting an error

> local variables referenced from lambda expression must be final or effectively final'.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your full code ?

Maybe try something like this :

```
int pos=0;
b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        String str=ta.getText();    //given text
        String srch=t1.getText();   //string to be searched
        pos = str.indexOf(srch,pos+1);
        ta.selectRange(pos, pos+srch.length());
    }
});
```